# How to ignore some words in a word cloud in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, word-cloud

In Python3 and Pandas I have this program to make word cloud from a column:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from wordcloud import WordCloud
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

autores_atuais = pd.read_csv("deputados_autores_projetos.csv", sep=',',encoding = 'utf-8', converters={'IdAutor': lambda x: str(x), 'IdDocumento': lambda x: str(x), 'CodOriginalidade': lambda x: str(x), 'IdNatureza': lambda x: str(x), 'NroLegislativo': lambda x: str(x)})

autores_atuais.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 6632 entries, 74057 to 84859
Data columns (total 10 columns):
IdAutor             6632 non-null object
IdDocumento         6632 non-null object
NomeAutor           6632 non-null object
AnoLegislativo      6632 non-null object
CodOriginalidade    5295 non-null object
DtEntradaSistema    6632 non-null object
DtPublicacao        6632 non-null object
Ementa              6632 non-null object
IdNatureza          6632 non-null object
NroLegislativo      6632 non-null object
dtypes: object(10)
memory usage: 569.9+ KB


wordcloud = WordCloud().generate(' '.join(autores_atuais['Ementa']))
plt.imshow(wordcloud)
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Please, how can I ignore some words from the cloud? For example, small words ("de", "ao") and certain words ("Estado")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `~` for inverse condition with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) for filter list of words with [`str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.len.html) for filter by length of words and if necessary chain conditions by `|`:

```
autores_atuais = pd.DataFrame({'Ementa':['Estado','another','be','de','def','bax']})

print (autores_atuais)
    Ementa
0   Estado
1  another
2       be
3       de
4      def
5      bax

m1 = autores_atuais['Ementa'].isin(['Estado','another','next'])
m2 = autores_atuais['Ementa'].str.len() < 3

s = autores_atuais.loc[~(m1 | m2), 'Ementa']
print (s)
4    def
5    bax
Name: Ementa, dtype: object
```

---

Similar alternative with `&` for `AND` and inverse first condition by `~` and second by `>=`:

```
m1 = ~autores_atuais['Ementa'].isin(['Estado','another','next'])
m2 = autores_atuais['Ementa'].str.len() >= 3

s = autores_atuais.loc[m1 & m2, 'Ementa']
print (s)
4    def
5    bax
Name: Ementa, dtype: object

wordcloud = WordCloud().generate(' '.join(s))
```

Comment: Thank you. But with this the generated word cloud is being created with the name of the columns, not with the words of the column "Ementa"

Comment: It looks like m1 and m2 exclude all rows with these words from the dataframe

Comment: @ReinaldoChaves - You are right, just modify answer.

Comment: Thank you again. I did so: m1 = ~autores_atuais['Ementa'].isin(['Constituição','Dispõe','Constituição', 'artigo'])
m2 = autores_atuais['Ementa'].str.len() >= 2

Comment: sobra = autores_atuais.loc[m1 & m2, 'Ementa']

Comment: But the cloud still has the words: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O3YfVsgLMaWetkqAhtPvC8Ob5CffSOKg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It seems to me that he does not rule out all the words

Comment: @ReinaldoChaves - I guess there are words like `de Interese` - 2 words in row.

Comment: Yes, a few words (such as "da Constituição") it considers with only one word. I do not know why

Comment: @ReinaldoChaves - need preprocessing like `autores_atuais['Ementa'] = autores_atuais['Ementa'].str.replace(r'\b\w{1,2}\b', '').str.strip()` for remove this.

Comment: @ReinaldoChaves the default value for the `collocations` parameter of the `WordCloud` object is `True`, which is why you're seeing this behaviour.

Comment: Thank you @ jezrael. Sorry, I still do not understand much of RE. This command does what, please? Do I need to replace some of it with words of interest?

Comment: @Reinaldo Chaves Mea culpa! Because dont explain it. So it replace all one and two characters words by empty string. If need replace also 3 character words, use `r'\b\w{1,3}\b'`' Also `\b` means word boundary. How does it work?

Answer (score 4):

I think you're using amueller's [`wordcloud`](https://amueller.github.io/word_cloud/) module? If so, there is a `stopwords` parameter which allows you to specify a file containing words to exclude.

So for example, if you create a textfile called `stopwords.txt` and save it in the same folder as your csv file, with this containing:

```
de
ao
Estado
```

And then change to:

```
wordcloud = WordCloud(stopwords='stopwords.txt').generate(' '.join(autores_atuais['Ementa']))
plt.imshow(wordcloud)
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

These words should correctly be excluded. The default set of words to be excluded is contained in the module folder, and should be called `stopwords`. If you're frequently going to be running into the same issues, it may be helpful to modify this default file here.

Comment: You can also import a list of stopwords from the `nltk` package. They have stopword lists from many languages available.  The nltk package is probably overkill if all you want is stopwords, but if you'll be using it anyway for other purposes it may be useful.

Comment: Thank you @asongtoruin. But some words continue to appear. It seems that the command understands that when certain words are together of others they have to be counted or that the union of them makes them different (like "da Constituição", "do Estado", "Constituição do"). These are words in Brazilian Portuguese. Could it be that?

Comment: Sorry, I have seen your comment below now

Answer (score 3):

To drop short words (say, 2 or less), you can use

```
autores_atuais = autores_atuais[autores_atuais.Ementa.str.len() <= 2]
```

To drop words in a list (say `restricted = ['Estado']`), you can use

```
autores_atuais = autores_atuais[~autores_atuais.Ementa.isin(restricted)]
```